# Azure Functions return IQueryable

Tags: azure-functions

I would like to build an API on Azure Functions but need to use Iqueryable with entityframework.

Is it possible to return an IQueryable from an azure function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace FunctionApp12
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        private static SortedDictionary<string, string> _dataValue;

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static IQueryable<object> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            _dataValue = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
            _dataValue.Add("test1", "This is test1.");
            IQueryable<object> query = _dataValue.AsQueryable().Select(r => r.Value);
            log.LogInformation("This is a test.");
            return query;
        }
    }
}
```

Hit the endpoint, you will get:

[image]